# loading fading in background image after settimeout with Kineticjs

Tags: fadein, kineticjs

Is it possible to change the background with an image fading in after a set time?
I am using the following code, but the image is not fading in. All I am achieving now is fading out the image with the transitionTo method, however I want it to fade in.
This is the code I am playing with:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 1770,
    height: 900
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var myBg = new Kinetic.Image({
     x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: imageObj,
      width: 1770,
      height: 900
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(myBg);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
setTimeout(function() {
    myBg.transitionTo({
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 4,
    });
  }, 3000);

  };
  imageObj.src = 'bg.png';
```

Can someone kindly shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you did not set initial opacity. What you were doing is setting opacity from 1 to 1, not from 0 to 1. please refer the following code.

```
var myBg = new Kinetic.Image({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  image: imageObj,
  opacity: 0,
  width: 1770,
  height: 900
});

myBg.transitionTo({
  opacity: 1,
  duration: 4,
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured that out later on, but didn't update my questions ;)